# Name lookup don't seem to work with nested classes

Tags: c++, class, nested, declaration

I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
template <typename E>
class SearchTree {
public:
    class Iterator {
             Iterator& operator++();
    };
};

template <typename E>
Iterator& SearchTree<E>::Iterator::operator++() {}
```

> warning C4346 : 'iterator' Dependent name is not a type
>
> error C2061 : Syntax error: identifier 'iterator'

Comment: [This code does not cause the error you are asking about.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90c441f6d55099ea) Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Fyi, once you fix that, the operator is still worthless (it's private). Regardless, I suspect this may be eventually helpful: [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 3):

You can use trailing return type to fix this:

```
template <typename E>
auto SearchTree<E>::Iterator::operator++() -> Iterator& {}
```

In the trailing return type, types can be inside the scope of the class. Before the `SearchTree<E>::` name lookup don't see inside the class.

Comment: Oooo! That's much better!

Answer (score 2):

It's a question about scope.

With

```
template <typename E>
Iterator& SearchTree<E>::Iterator::operator++() {}
```

when you use the symbol `Iterator` for the return type, that type isn't known in that scope. You have to specify its scope:

```
template <typename E>
typename SearchTree<E>::Iterator& SearchTree<E>::Iterator::operator++() {}
```

As mentioned in comments and other answers, you can also use a *trailing return type*. This is possible because then the scope is known.

---

On a related note, and why I added the `typename` keyword for the return type, see [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: A shorter way to do it: `auto SearchTree<E>::Iterator::operator++() -> Iterator& {}`

Answer (score 0):

You want to fully specify the return value:

```
template <typename E>
SearchTree<E>::Iterator& SearchTree<E>::Iterator::operator++() {}
```